# Apple HIG: Zoom In or Zoom in?

Tags: ios, hig

Apple HIG states this about capitalization for buttons:

> **Use title-case for titles.** Capitalize every word except articles, coordinating conjunctions, and prepositions of four or fewer letters.

But violates its own rule here:

[image]

So should I use "Zoom Out" or "Zoom out" for a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*zoom out* is a phrasal verb (see [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/zoom-out)), and consists of a verb and a particle (see [Phrasal verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb) on Wikipedia). This means *out* is not a preposition here, so *Zoom Out* is correct.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know *zoom out* was a phrasal verb. This seems gratuitous since *in* and *out* have plain meaning for the verb *zoom*. That contrasts with *throw up* which is more clearly a phrasal verb.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all style guides for the English language state the following, as the first rule of capitalization:

**Always capitalize the first and the last word.**

*Zoom Out* is the correct capitalization.

Comment: I've never heard a rule where you should capitalize the last word. Where is this rule applied? Only in cases where the sentence is two words long or should I be capitalizing the last word of every sentence like This?

Comment: @BoleTzar is talking about title case here. So the article would be capitalized if it's the last word in the title: "Let the Cat In."

Comment: "Who Let the Dogs Out?"